# How to call a Django function from template and save return in a variable

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

**Context:**

I have a piece of HTML that I want to dispaly in the template just in case a function return "true".

**Details:**

My function

```
def show_avg_kpi():
    return config.avg_times_visible
register.filter('show_avg_kpi', show_avg_kpi)
```

Template ( is the piece of code to display or not):

```
{% if show_avg_kpi %}
  <HTML CODE>
{% endif %}
```

I want something like this, but I don't know how to save the result of the show_avg_kpi function in a variable to use it with the {% if %} tags

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using it everywhere in all templates or just in one template ?

Comment: Just in a one template

Answer (score 1):

You can use `register.simple_tag` like this

```
@register.simple_tag
def show_avg_kpi():
    return config.avg_times_visible
```

and in your template like this

```
{% show_avg_kpi as your_var %}
{% if your_var %}
    your code
{% endif %}
```

Now show_avg_kpi will be called only once

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [{% with %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tags. i.e:

```
{% with my_var=show_avg_kpi %} 
    {% if my_var=condition %}
        HTML CODE
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

But you can only use my_var inside the **with statement**.

Another approach is to send the variable from the view.